# How to delete section of UITableView on click of view in swift3

Tags: ios, swift3

I want to remove a table cell on click of view which is on cell in swift3.

Following function is called on click of View and remove method is used to delete table section.But this solution is not working.

```
func remove(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
        {
            let indexView = sender.view
            let index = indexView?.tag

            self.removeAddresses(position: index!)
        }

    func remove(position: Int)  
    {  
        tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(index: position,with. automatic))  
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: You want to remove whole section or just one row(cell) ? also show us your datasource method of your tableView.

Comment: ok.. if you want to remove a cell then in you tap method just write as  [yourItemArray removeObjectAtIndex:itemIndex];
        [yourTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathCreated] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

Comment: Add you datasource methods in question

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
func remove(position: Int)  
    {  
        yourDataSourceArray?.removeAtIndex(position)

        tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(index: position,with. automatic))  
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To remove a table cell, I suggest you can use Editing Style

**Methods:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

            }   
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

}        
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {

        }
```

2. And I think ,

   ```
     func remove(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
               let indexView = sender.view
               let index = indexView?.tag       
               self.removeAddresses(position: index!)         
           }

     func removeAddresses(position: Int){  
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        yourDataSourceArray.removeObject(at: position)
        table.deleteRows(at: [indexPathCreated] , with: .automatic)
        table.endUpdates()
      }
   ```